# how to reverse search a value in sql

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a search box for numbers that are in database. my search criteria is that it should get the number even the number is typed in reverse
like "447663" is my number when i type 366(which is in reverse) it should get it

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Ideally this should be done in db. You should pass searched string and then do your permutations in db to fetch records

Answer (score 0):

You can convert and revert

```
 select yourcolumn
 from your table
 where ( reverse(convert(youcolumn, char)) like '%366';
```

Comment: Reversing the Passing Parameter Value Would Be Better , I think. :)

Comment: Could be but the question remain the same.